# Simplifying the $\frac{d}{dx} \left(x/(x+c/x)\right)$

Tags: calculus

I have been using the quotient rule for derivatives; however, I am having trouble simplifying my answer of $(cx+x)/(x^2+c)^2$ to the books answer of $2cx/(x^2+c)^2$.

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong? Thanks...

Comment: Well, but $(cx+x)/(x^2+c)^2 \not = 2cx/(x^2+c)^2$ for general $c \not = 1$ though.  So there has to be a typo somewhere...

Comment: Can you tell how you got $(cx+x)/(x^2+c)^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go slowly:
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{x+\dfrac{c}{x}}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+c}=\frac{x^2+c-c}{x^2+c}=
1-\frac{c}{x^2+c}
$$
Therefore, by the chain rule applied to the function $g(u)=1/u$, with $u=x^2+c$, we have
$$
f'(x)=\frac{c}{(x^2+c)^2}\cdot 2x=\frac{2cx}{(x^2+c)^2}
$$
If you want to apply the quotient rule *directly* to the expression of $f(x)$, then
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1\left(x+\dfrac{c}{x}\right)-x\left(1-\dfrac{c}{x^2}\right)}{\left(x+\dfrac{c}{x}\right)^{\!2}}=
\frac{x+\dfrac{c}{x}-x+\dfrac{c}{x}}{\dfrac{(x^2+c)^2}{x^2}}=\frac{2c}{x}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+c)^2}=\frac{2cx}{(x^2+c)^2}
$$

It's generally much better to simplify expressions as much as possible before starting to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

Once you multiply top and bottom by $x/x = 1$, and apply quotient rule, the numerator is $2x(x^2+c)-2x(x^2)$ which simplifies nicely to $2xc.$

Comment: Do you mean "multiply by $x/x$", or possibly "multiply top and bottom by $x$"?

Comment: Ah yes my wording is wrong, I meant multiply top and bottom by x, i.e the entire fraction by x\x